# How might I automatically characterize scatterplots of related datasets? Examples included

Tags: matlab, statistics

[Test data along the length (x-axis) of one batch of our product.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5JNZ.jpg)

I am trying to characterize this data in some way. Each batch has a similarly shaped scatter plot of values, but they vary in scale and location along the y-axis. [Here is a different batch from the product showing the kinds of differences that might be expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEkft.jpg).

The data cannot be fit to a polynomial function because of those two peaks at x = 15 and x = 115, though a 6th or 7th degree polynomial is a decent approximation.

So: do you have any ideas how I might be able to create some function that describes this pattern using variables for scale and location on the y-axis?

The data is expected to be split right down the middle at about x = 57 since the product is symmetrical, though there may be times when one side has values that don't perfectly match the other.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps something like this could be a starting point? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23611

Answer (score 0):

If x = 15 and x = 115 are constants, then you can divide the data into 3 parts and then use 3 simple functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of your problem as being split into two parts:

1. Find the right function
2. Fit the function to the data

Finding the right function is a bit more art than science.  As you have pointed out, a high degree polynomial can fit your data.  A polynomial of arbitrary degree can fit any curve in a given region!  It may not be the best *model* for your data, but it will give you a fantastic fit.

What do you need to be able to compare between the two results?  Are you more interested in the noise?  Are you interested in the height of the peaks?  The derivative of the smoothed function?  The location of the peaks?  An answer to that question will tell you how best to find the right function.  A good portal for further detail is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection

As for the second portion, fitting the function is actually quite simple.  If you have a relatively low-dimensional function, you can use `fminsearch` to find the "optimal" parameters.  It will get you a local minimum, but based on experience, it does a pretty good job!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to characterize a single data set (i.e., the data plotted on a single set of axes) or are you more interested in *characterizing the variance among the various batches*? When i read your Question it seemed to me it was the latter, but the answers so far seem to assume the former.

If indeed it's the latter, this is a common task in time-series analysis (i.e., *residual* analysis) the steps of which are:

- if one data set is a sensible benchmark (i.e, a reference or
  calibrated batch) then use mark it as such;
- if not, then create a benchmark by calculating a mean vector from all
  each data set;
- for each data set, calculate a variance vector (or an absolute
  variance vector) and plot it--these are the ***residuals***;
- finally, you can calculate the mean absolute variance for all data
  sets and plot.